# StackOverflowError when calling Spring Data MongoDB repository method with a page size bigger than 36

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stack-overflow, spring-data-mongodb

I am getting a StackOverflowError when calling a method of my MongoDB repository interface:

```
public interface TermRepository extends MongoRepository<Term, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Term> {
    // [...]
    @Query("{$or:[{'apis' : {$in : ?0 } }, {$text:{$search:?1}}]}")
    Page<Term> globalSearch(List<DBRef> apis, String searchKeyword, Pageable pageable);
}
```

- `apis` is a list with just one DBRef: new DBRef("api", new ObjectId("5e3ad9faaafa595898b6a682"))
- `searchKeyword` equals "accounts"
- `pageable` is `Page request [number: 0, size 37, sort: UNSORTED]`. If `size` is 36, it doesn't throw the StackOverflowError!
- The query gets translated into

```
{
    $or: [{
        'apis': {
            $in: [{
                '$ref': 'api',
                '$id': ObjectId('5e3ad9faaafa595898b6a682')
            }]
        }
    }, {
        $text: {
            $search: 'account'
        }
    }]
}
```

- If I execute the query directly in mongo, it returns 55 elements.
- I've tried to increase thread stack to -Xss1G (it's a lot, I know), and it just keeps filling the stack slowly and won't return. If I rerun the test with a page size of 36, it returns immediately.

Does anyone have a clue what's happening?

The Term:

```
public class Term {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    @TextIndexed
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @TextIndexed
    @JsonProperty
    private String objectType;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty
    private String snakeCase;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty
    private List<String> functionalCategories;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private TermTypeEnum termType;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, String> description;

    @Setter
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private TermStateEnum state;

    @NotBlank
    @TextIndexed
    @JsonProperty
    private String example;

    @DBRef
    @NotNull
    @Indexed
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Api> apis;

    @DBRef
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private User contributor;

    @NotBlank
    @TextIndexed
    @JsonProperty
    private String version;

    @DBRef
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Term> attributes;
}
```

The stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/y0XYt7p6

Although there might be a circular reference because Term has an attribute Map<String, Term>, I think it's not a circular reference what is producing the stack overflow.

Doing some debug, I saw that the stack overflow occurs because in the end spring-data keeps instantiating this Term only (not others, so I don't see the circular reference):

```
Term(id=5e3ad9faaafa595898b6a7ea, name=debitCurrency, objectType=string, snakeCase=debit_currency, functionalCategories=null, termType=BODY, description={"english"=Debit Currency.}, state=PROPOSED, example=null, apis=[Api(id=5e3ad9faaafa595898b6a67f, name=Payments-1.0.1, description=null, responsible=null)], contributor=null, version=null, attributes=null)
```

Which in turn does not reference other terms.

Here is another Term, just for comparison:

```
Term(id=5e3ad9faaafa595898b6a6c8, name=displayCardNumber, objectType=string, snakeCase=display_card_number, functionalCategories=null, termType=BODY, description={"english"=Related card number to the account.}, state=PROPOSED, example=null, apis=[Api(id=5e3ad9faaafa595898b6a682, name=Accounts-1.0.2, description=null, responsible=null)], contributor=null, version=null, attributes=null)
```

I see no difference, but `debitCurrency` produces the stack overflow and `displayCardNumber` doesn't.

Comment: I don't see anything regarding paging that could cause that... If I were you, I would check to see if the data in the 37th record looks correct.  In particular, your 'Term' contains 'attributes' that are themselves Terms... so there is a chance that some code related to nested attributes might get executed on the 37th record and not the first 36, and end up going into an infinite recursion or something like that.  Just an idea.  In fact, I find it likely that there is a circular reference of in the attributes Map, since it is a DBRef which gets autofetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a circular reference (self-reference more accurately) indeed.

I've come up with a workaround that consists of making the `@DBRef` of attributes, `lazy=true`, and implementing a custom serializer of the class `Term`, wich has the self-reference (or circular reference). The reason of implementing the custom serializer, is that I can save a set of the objects that have already been serialized, and if I have to seralize an object again, I just don't.